# Best way to store person data (first name, last name) in database

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I am just wondering which is more recommended when it comes about storing person names in a database.

The first is, that I have the table, with two dedicated columns, such as: FamilyName, GivenName, both of them are string type and we store the family name (or family names if there are more than one) and same with given names.
This will end up with a structure like

```
+-------------------------------+
|              PERSON           |
+-------------+------------+----+
| FamilyName  | Given Name | ID |
+-------------+------------+----+
| Doe         | John       |  1 |
| Doe         | Peter      |  2 |
| Williamson  | Williams   |  3 |
| Hansen      | Williams   |  4 |
+-------------+------------+----+
```

Or another approach is that I have a separated table where I store only names, and in the name table I have foreign key references to that table, and I have a more complex relationship person table, as represented below:

```
+-----------------+
| NAME_STRINGS    |
+---+-------------+
|ID | VALUE       |
+---+-------------+
| 1 | Doe         |
| 2 | John        |
| 3 | Hansen      |
| 4 | Peter       |
| 5 | Williamson  |
| 6 | Williams    |
+---+-------------+

+-------------------------------+
|              PERSON           |
+-------------+------------+----+
|FamilyNameId | GivenNameId| ID |
+-------------+------------+----+
| 1           | 2          |  1 |
| 1           | 4          |  2 |
| 5           | 6          |  3 |
| 3           | 6          |  4 |
+-------------+------------+----+
```

Please note, that I am not considering complex cases, such as double, triple or middle names, I am more interested in the concept of eliminating data duplication. Is it worth overcomplicating a solution like this for a database that will have around ~10 000 000 unique persons, but sharing a lot of common names?

Comment: I think your second approach is more useful.

Comment: The second approach is totally overcomplicating it. "the concept of eliminating data duplication" is not a sufficient reason to do this. Complicated systems break more and are harder to fix.

Comment: I like normalization, but I've never gone to this degree of normalization with names.  The answer is probably more opinion based though.

Comment: I would go with the first one. Even though normalization helps in many cases, you don't want to overnormalizate your database. Always go natural ;)

Comment: First approach is much better. There is no significant benefit of decreasing stroing data in the second one but it will slow down your select queries because of joins.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your situation but if you are not going to store any more data in your table about a specific name (what is the latin version, what's the history of the name etc.) then you would definitely go with one table with `firstname` and `lastname` columns.

From a normalization standpoint it would make sense if either `firstname` or `lastname` would be dependent on any other factor than the `id` of the person. As it is, you can't tell a persons name by looking at his/her `address`, `position` or any other data stored in the database. Neither can you tell his `lastname` by looking at his `firstname` or vice versa. You can only say his name is functionally dependent of his uniquely individual `id`.

If you had `name_info` field with info like "John is derived from latin Johannes", then it would not make sense to repeat the info for every John in the database and thus it should be moved to another table.

Answer (score 0):

The deep of [data normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) depends on many factors. In this case i'd suggest to change nothing. Let's say there are hundreds of John Doe's. I think you need to get another attribute which uniqually identify each of them, for example: Personal ID.

For further information, please see:
[Description of the database normalization basics](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878?wa=wsignin1.0)
[Introduction to Data Normalization: A Database "Best" Practice](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html)
[Normalization of Database](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)